# How to know the free space size for directories /usr, /var

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using AWS ubuntu instance (Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM)), by default the data of neo4j is stored into /var/lib/neo4j, so i wanna check the free space size for directory /var, when i executed **df -h**, i got below info, is it because /var are not fiesystem, let's why they're not showing. Is there a way to check the free space size for directories like /var, /usr. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            992M     0  992M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  5.7M  195M   3% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  2.7G  5.1G  35% /
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find disk usage per directory, using `du -sh`

Ex. `du -sh /var`, `du -sh /usr`

There's nothing like free space per directory, as there are no size limits on directories by default.

Comment: Hi Acsrujan, Thanks for ur reply, but how to know directory /var is located in which device, at least need to know the free space size of the device, thanks!

Comment: `df -h` tells you free space size of the device. And `/var` is located on `/dev/xvda1`, by default. In your case, there's no device other than xvda.

`tmpfs` is volatile filesystem launched by OS and `udev` is device manager in Linux.

So, in your case, /dev/xvda1 has 2.7GB used and if `du -sh /var` tells you /var directory is using 1.2G, then you can look further into which directories are holding the space.

Answer (score 0):

use `df -k /var` - will give you available and used space.

```
# df -k /var
Filesystem           1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx
                      30122960 3376344  25209800  12% /var
```